# Springfox swagger-ui.html not loading

Tags: java, swagger

Im trying to acces the swagger ui page, but when i'm gonna acces the page, this error comes up

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback

[image: error]

My project tree:
[image: project]

The swagger Config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.aluno"))
                .paths(regex("/api.*"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(metaInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo metaInfo() {

        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
                "Cursos API REST",
                "API REST de registro de alunos.",
                "1.0",
                "Terms of Service",
                new Contact("Romulo Sorato", "https://www.linkedin.com/in/r%C3%B4mulo-sorato-domingos-a6524437/",
                        "romulosorato@hotmail.com"),
                "Apache License Version 2.0",
                "https://www.apache.org/licesen.html", new ArrayList<>()
        );

        return apiInfo;
    }
}
```

My pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Why i cant acces the swagger-ui?

Looks like even tomcat is launching.
I added the correct depencies on pom.xml

Comment: I have posted an answer.  @RômuloSorato The version you used was the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you want to use Springfox3. If yes, then try the following changes.

**Remove springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui and add below dependency in pom.xml**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

**SwaggerConfig - remove `@EnableSwagger2` annotation**

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.aluno"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(metaInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo metaInfo() {

        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
                "Cursos API REST",
                "API REST de registro de alunos.",
                "1.0",
                "Terms of Service",
                new Contact("Romulo Sorato", "https://www.linkedin.com/in/r%C3%B4mulo-sorato-domingos-a6524437/",
                        "romulosorato@hotmail.com"),
                "Apache License Version 2.0",
                "https://www.apache.org/licesen.html", new ArrayList<>()
        );

        return apiInfo;
    }
}
```

**For this version, URL of UI has been changed as shown below:**

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html
```

If you want **to use older version** then just use version `2.9.2` (works perfectly fine for me). No other changes required in your config file or UI's URL.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: For more details have look this official [doc](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#migrating-from-existing-2-x-version). It has clear explanation on migration from 2.x version.

Answer (score 1):

could you please try this, it works for me

```
@Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()                                       
                  .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.aluno.controller"))
                  .paths(PathSelectors.any())                   
                  .build();
    }
```

could you please check, these dependencies are added

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: It still dont work, i think it needs to be the base package

Comment: i have tried it by keeping this bean in base package

Comment: Didnt work too, the SwaggerConfig class doesnt need to be in the base package only the  main sprigboot class

Comment: could you please check that the edited dependencies are added

Comment: Could you please share log that would be helpful

Comment: @GomathyM you have used version 2.7.0. Thats why it worked fine for you. Even It worked fine for me when I used 2.9.2.